# How to merge data values from different files with inconsistent "Datetime"?

Tags: awk, merge

I have to merge 2 files with data from May to Sep for 10 year period. In the first file I have data in 30 min interval (two columns - one is Datetime), and the Datetime is inconsistent. The second file has less data, but 4 columns -  one is Datetime, because it is for 3 hour period, again Datetime is inconsistent. So far I tried the following:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1]=$NF;next} FNR!=NR && FNR>1{Q=$1;$0=(Q in A)?$0 FS A[$1]:$0 FS;print;next} {print}' FS="\t"  Synop.txt Gnss.txt  > new.dat
```

But the result is that I fail to add 3 columns but only one, otherwise I think it matches the Datetime.

Here is example:

file1:

```
Datetime        IWV
2012-05-07 15:00:00     9.74
2012-05-07 15:30:00     9.84
2012-05-07 16:00:00     9.95
2012-05-07 16:30:00     10.11
2012-05-07 17:00:00     10.24
2012-05-07 17:30:00     10.37
2012-05-07 18:00:00     10.46
```

file2:

```
Datetime        Phenomena       Past_Phenomena_1        Precipitation_3h
2012-05-07 18:00:00     17      9       0.1
2012-05-08 15:00:00     29      9       0
2012-05-10 15:00:00     95      9       0
2012-05-22 15:00:00     95      9       0
2012-05-24 12:00:00     17      9       0
2012-06-01 15:00:00     17      9       0
2012-06-04 15:00:00     17      9       0
2012-06-05 06:00:00     17      9       4.2
2012-06-11 15:00:00     17      9       0
```

I want to keep "IWV" data and Datetime and add (if any) Phenomena,Past_Phenomena_1,Precipitation_3h.

Expected outcome:

```
2012-05-07 15:00:00   9.74
2012-05-07 15:30:00   9.84
2012-05-07 16:00:00   9.95
2012-05-07 16:30:00   10.11
2012-05-07 17:00:00   10.24
2012-05-07 17:30:00   10.37
2012-05-07 18:00:00   10.46   17   9   0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR{ Q=$1; $1=""; Datetime[Q]=$0; next }
FNR>1  { print $0 Datetime[$1] }' file2 file1
```